# Terminal Color Breaking the Prompt - Cmd Module

Tags: terminal, colorama, python-cmd

I am using `cmd` module and `colorama` module, when I use `colorama` module to add color to the prompt it's just breaking the prompt. If I run the script without color then it's working fine

Sample Image

[image: screenshot]

I tried google, there are some solution for bash but I tried those in python, but it's not working

is there any way I could fix this?